# "One who calls others to worship" - A specific term?

Tags: single-word-requests

This would be referring to a position likely held in the ancient world. I thought it was 'hierophant', but that turned out to be wrong. I do have the impression that the two words are related, and vague as it may be I think it starts with an 'S'.

An example would be "The doors of the temple were opened, and the ______ stepped out to announce the start of the rites."

Comment: I would say that it depends on the religion.

Comment: Muezzin (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Muezzin)  or  Schulklopfer (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schulklopfer)

Comment: No single word will work. In the past, some Western Churches had an "enunciator" who  called to worship, among other tasks.

Comment: You could use a generic term for a religious person, such as "cleric".

Comment: while not exactly a religious word,  a "crier"  might sound ok given that it's antiquity sort of translates to 'traditionally' which translates well to formal religious services

Comment: Two words related: convoke and synod.  Convoker is a possible noun, but probably not what you're thinking of.

Comment: "Summoner" would be perfect, and it's even a historic church office; unfortunately, a summoner delivers a summons to appear in court, rather than a summons to worship.  Ah well.

Comment: many religions ... many names.

Comment: One might use "cantor" -- a chant leader in several religions.

Answer (score -1):

I think you can consider using a generic term such as ***preacher***:

> - **b** : one whose function is to preach sermons : pastor, minister
>
>   - She waited patiently on a Sunday morning until the crowd had said good-by to the *preacher*. —Don Jeffries
>   - "What kind of *preacher* are you? What denomination?" "I was ordained in a Baptist church, but I'm sort of nondenominational now. " —John Grisham
>
> <sub>[Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/preacher)</sub>

If you need something more specific to the task of *initiating* the call to worship, you could consider using ***herald***:

> An official messenger bringing news.
>   <sub>[Oxford *Living* Dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/herald)</sub>

Answer (score -1):

In the ancient Jewish religion, the person in charge of blowing the ram's horn, or shofar (**שופר‎**), was called a [Tokea](https://www.thoughtco.com/what-is-a-shofar-2076493) (which literally means “blaster”), and it is no easy task to perform each of these sounds.

Not only would the Tokea summon people to worship, but according to [Ariela Pelaia](https://www.thoughtco.com/what-is-a-shofar-2076493) he also used the shofar to announce the start of holidays, in processions, and even to mark the start of a war.

Pelaia goes on to say,

> Perhaps the most famous biblical reference to the shofar occurs in the Book of Joshua, where shofarot (plural of shofar) were used as part of a battle plan to capture the city of Jericho:
>
> Then the LORD said to Joshua… March around the city once with all the
>   armed men. Do this for six days. Have seven priests carry trumpets of
>   rams' horns in front of the ark. On the seventh day, march around the
>   city seven times, with the priests blowing the trumpets. When you hear
>   them sound a long blast on the trumpets, have all the people give a
>   loud shout; then the wall of the city will collapse and the people
>   will go up, every man straight in (Joshua 6:2-5).